# How do i extract from a nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created a nested dictionary with the following:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, string>> dateDict =
    new Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

I then enter values to this dictionary using the following:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(reader["Event_Date"].ToString());
    string name = reader["Event_Name"].ToString();
    string guid = reader["Event_GUID"].ToString();
    dateDict.Add(date, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    dateDict[date].Add(name, guid);
}
```

My question is how do I correctly pull the variables back out from the nested dictionary?

I have this loop running to pull values out and assign them to DateTimePickers and TextFields:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateDict.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime keyVar = dateDict.ElementAt(i).Key;
    eventDateBoxes[i].Value = keyVar;
    eventTextBoxes[i].Text = dateDict[keyVar[]];
}
```

The eventTextBoxes part is where im getting stuck on how to pull the value from the nested dictionary, hence why that part of the code is wrong/incomplete.

I can't use tuples as I am using .NET lower than 4 and can't seem to wrap my head around making a custom class to act as its own tuple or multidictionary.

Comment: `dateDict[keyVar]` would give you the `Dictionary<string,string>`, but how do you want to convert that to a single `string`?  You could do `string.Join(";", dataDict[keyVar].Select(kvp => kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value)` to get a semicolon delimited string of "key=value" pairs.

Comment: @juharr im looking just to get the key or the value from the nested dictionary, not both at the same time. Im storing 3 things, a DateTime, String (name) and string(GUID) which are database values

Comment: What is `eventDateBoxes`? How you want to format the text if there are multiple events per date?

Comment: @TimSchmelter eventDateBoxes is a List<DateTimePicker>

Comment: If you only need a DateTime to pair of strings then either use `Tuple<string, string>` or a custom class like `class MyClass { public string Thing1{get;set;} public string Thing2 {get;set;}}` don't use a nested `Dictionary` for that.

Comment: @juharr could you elaborate more on that in an answer? As stated im not able to use Tuple's due to being on .NET below 4 but struggled to understand making a custom class for it, if you could expand on it id be happy to mark it an the answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need a `Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, string>>` since you have only one item inside your inner dictionary, you need a `Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, Event>>` where `Event` is a class that holds you event data. Something like:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Guid {get; set;}  // you could actually use the GUID type here!
}
```

Then you'd populate it like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(reader["Event_Date"].ToString());
    string name = reader["Event_Name"].ToString();
    string guid = reader["Event_GUID"].ToString();
    dateDict.Add(date, new Event() { Name = name, Guid = guid };
}
```

Then when you get an item from your dictionary by key:

```
var item = dateDict[someKey];
```

You can get your name and guid back:

```
var name = item.Name;
var guid = item.guid;
```

Additionally, since you are iterating through your dictionary by numerical index rather than by key, it seems likely that you probably don't need a dictionary at all. Maybe all you need to do is add a `Date` property to your `Event` and just have an `List<Event>`.

Comment: Worked a treat! Was getting stuck on how id call the values from the class without assigning them a name, realized i dont need to after trying this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic outline of what you would do:

```
foreach (var element in dateDict)
{
    eventDateBoxes[i].Value = element.Key;
    foreach (var subElement in element.Value)
    {
        eventTextBoxes[i].Text = subElement.Value;
    }
}
```

As others point out in the comment, there can be no one-to-one relationship between the elements in the outer dictionary and the text boxes as there can (potentially) be multiple entries in the sub-element.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `foreach` or a LINQ query. But it's not clear what you want as `DateTimePicker.Text`:

```
List<DateTimePicker> eventDateBoxes = dateDict
    .Select(kv => new{ 
       Date = kv.Key, 
       EventName = kv.Value["Event_Name"],
       EventGuid = kv.Value["Event_GUID"],
    })
    .Select(x => new DateTimePicker{ Value = x.Date, Text = x.EventName })
    .ToList();
```